# PHP: Convert date to Javascript date (January = zero)

Tags: php, date, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and need the dates formatted like this:

```
UTC.(2016,11,01) // for December 1st 2016
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Because

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month'))
```

gives me the wrong output for January.

Comment: can you eventually also write what is the input you give, what is the expected result and what is the actual result ?

Comment: You need to specify the parts of your date separately, What you're trying to do is literally adjust the date to an earlier date, which is always going to be problematic. I would declare your year, month, and day as individual variables (or an array), and populate them in your javascript accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sub the month. Just use other format as ATOM/RFC3339. It's fully supported by [javascript Date class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-01-01');
echo $date->format(DateTime::ATOM);
```

Result:

```
2016-01-01T00:00:00-05:00
```

Javascript:

```
var date = new Date('2016-01-01T00:00:00-05:00');
console.log(date)
```

As I'm live in Brazil, my browser show as

```
Fri Jan 01 2016 03:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão)
```

If you have any other format as input, you could use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and the rest still the same

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y' , '12/01/2016');
```